# Nullable is not a ValueType

Tags: c#, nullable

If you look at the documentation for the .NET Nullable, you'll see:

```
   struct Nullable<T>
```

Note that it's a **struct**, not a class.

It seems a `struct Nullable<T>` is **not** a ValueType, which is very unexpected. The following code prints False:

```
   Type nullableType = typeof(Nullable<int>);
   Console.WriteLine(nullableType is ValueType);
```

If you look at the generated IL you'll see that that compiler determined `nullableType` to be a ValueType at compile time. But how can it be a ValueType if it's a struct? All structs are ValueTypes, right? Obviously, it has something to do with the generic.

What am I missing here? Is there something in the language spec about this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is funny to see two answers, one claiming it isn't a value type and one claiming it is and both answers have about the same number of upvotes. Clearly you've asked a question without a clear cut answer. I'd say a Nullable is neither a struct nor a class, but a hack provided by the C# compiler.

Comment: You should read the answers more carefully. They both say that Nullable is in fact a value type and that @Tom is accidentally checking if Type is a value type

Answer (score 15):

You are testing if `System.Type` is a value type.  It is not.  Rewrite it like this:

```
Nullable<int> test = 42;
Console.WriteLine(test is ValueType);
```

Comment: If you attempt to output the type of "test", you'll find that when HasValue is true it gets boxed as an Int32, and when HasValue is false it gets boxed as null.  In neither case is it boxed as a Nullable<Int32>.  Int32 is a value type, but that doesn't mean Nullable<Int32> is.

Answer (score 12):

It is a value type, try it this way:

```
Type nullableType = typeof(Nullable<int>);
Console.WriteLine(nullableType.IsValueType);
```

That should return true. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Tom Happens to everyone once in a while. =] Anyway, as they seemed to have answered your question, you should accept one of these answers by clicking that checkmark under the vote number.

Answer (score 2):

`Nullable<T>` is a generic family of types that obey the rules of neither value types nor class types.  Run-time methods for checking an object's type require boxing.  If the `HasValue` property of a `Nullable<T>` is `true`, an attempt to box it will decompose it into a `T` and box that.  Otherwise, an attempt to box it will yield `null`.  In no case will it get boxed as a `Nullable<T>`.  It's possible to construct a Type object for `Nullable<T>`, and the `IsValueType` of such a `Type` object will return `true`, and analysis of memory usage will confirm that a `Nullable<T>` is stored as a value type, but since it disobeys some of the rules that are applicable to all other value types, `` `Nullable<T> ``'s are best regarded as being a unique kind of entity.

Comment: Nullable<T> has a generic constraint where T : struct . So it always obeys the rule of System.ValueType for the T. Boxing and unboxing comes into picture when working with methods overridden from System.Object.

Comment: @Dinesh: Type `Nullable<T>` is stored as a value type, but as noted it has enough weird behaviors that it's regarded as a unique kind of entity. Boxing isn't only necessary when invoking `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, and `Equals` on a `Nullable<T>` whose `T` doesn't provide its own implementations, but also when casting a `Nullable<T>` to a reference type.